# Adding multiple Events to an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Lets say i have the following code:

```
function addScrollEvent(scrollElement, direction) { 
    $(scrollElement).mouseover(function(){
        var maxStreckeY = $("#viewport div").height() - $("#viewport").innerHeight();
        var currentPos = $("#viewport").scrollTop();
        if (direction == "down") {
            var restStrecke = maxStreckeY - currentPos;
            var timer = restStrecke / maxStreckeY *  namespace.config.autoScrollSpeed;
            $(element).stop().animate({scrollTop: maxStreckeY}, timer);
        }
        if (direction == "right") {
            var width = $("#viewport div").width();
            $(element).stop().animate({scrollLeft: width - $("#viewport").innerWidth()}, namespace.config.autoScrollSpeed);
        }
        if (direction == "up") {
            var timer = currentPos / maxStreckeY *  namespace.config.autoScrollSpeed;
            $(element).stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, timer);   
        }
        if (direction == "left") {
            $(element).stop().animate({scrollLeft: 0}, namespace.config.autoScrollSpeed);
        }
    });

    $(scrollElement).mouseleave(function(){
        $(element).stop();
        checkScrollElements();
    });
```

How do i append multiple events to the scrollElement? i would like to do the exact code on tabhold (at the mouseover part) and also on tableave (at the mouseleave part)

I already tried to do something like this :

```
$(scrollElement).on("mouseover tabhold", function(){
    ... the function
});
```

which did not really work since the console gave me the following error :

```
"on is not a function"
```

Anybody got a solution for this without copying the same code for another event block? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? if old version (<1.7) then use `live()` instead of `on()`

Comment: Im using the jQuery Version 1.6

Comment: Instead of declaring the behaviour for the handler inside the addEventListener function, define it as a separate function and pass a reference to the function in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `on` solution is correct; the problem is you're using an obsolete copy of jQuery. v1.6 was outdated by v1.7 **four years ago**. Upgrade to the latest.

If for some reason you can't, the old function is [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$(scrollElement).bind("mouseover tabhold", function(){
    ... the function
});
```

Another option is to write the function separately, give it a name, and use that name. One advantage to that is it lets you use the function in combination with others if needed.

Comment: So why did they invent 3 diffrent types for multiple event handling? i dont understand. anyway this solved my problem. at least i dont get any errors this way. i will try with my tablet and check out whether it works or not :)

Comment: @TeaTime: Originally it was `bind`. Then event delegation was added in the form of `live` and `delegate`. Then they decided it was silly to have two different APIs, one for direct handling and another for delegation, and separately there were multiple issues with `live`. So they decided to create a new, unified API that did both direct and delegated handling, and they called it `on`.